# What does it mean to deploy a web site/webapp

Tags: web, webserver, web-hosting

When it comes to web development, I've heard of the terms web hosting and web server being thrown around. What is the difference and when is each used ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Web hosting in simple term can be explain like like business of housing ,serving or maintaining files for one or more websites.
When Internet users want to view your website, all they need to do is type your website address or domain into their browser. Their computer will then connect to your server and your webpages will be delivered to them through the browser.
```